# std::find not using my defined == operator

Tags: c++, stl, std

I have a simple class that I am storing in a vector as pointers. I want to use a find on the vector but it is failing to find my object. Upon debugging it doesn't seem to call the == operator I've provided. I can 'see' the object in the debugger so I know its there. The code below even uses a copy of the first item in the list, but still fails. The only way I can make it pass is to use MergeLine* mlt = LineList.begin(), which shows me that it is comparing the objects and not using my equality operator at all.

```
class MergeLine {
public:
   std::string linename;
   int StartIndex;
   double StartValue;
   double FidStart;
   int Length; 

   bool operator <  (const MergeLine &ml) const {return FidStart < ml.FidStart;}
   bool operator == (const MergeLine &ml) const {
         return linename.compare( ml.linename) == 0;}    
};

Class OtherClass{
public:
   std::vector<MergeLine*>LineList;
   std::vector<MergeLine*>::iterator LL_iter;
   void DoSomething( std::string linename){
 // this is the original version that returned LineList.end()
 //   MergeLine * mlt
 //   mlt->linename = linename;

 // this version doesn't work either (I thought it would for sure!)
      MergeLine *mlt =new MergeLine(*LineList.front());
      LL_iter = std::find(LineList.begin(), LineList.end(), mlt);
      if (LL_iter == LineList.end()) {
         throw(Exception("line not found in LineList : " + mlt->linename));
      }
      MergeLine * ml = *LL_iter;

    }
};
```

cheers,
Marc

Comment: Of course not. `a == b` isn't the same as `*a == *b`...

Comment: Pointers are built-in types, so they don't use overloaded `operator==`

Comment: Any particular reason for which you store in your vector pointers to MergeLine, instead of plain MergeLine objects? Besides, wouldn't it be a smart pointer more suitable for your needs?

Comment: @Antonio, frankly I can't remember why I implemented it as a pointer. Looking back through my code, I can reimplement it as objects fairly easily. I'll probably do that.

Comment: @JesseGood & KerrekSB, I get it. Since there is a predefined pointer comparison it uses that instead of dereferencing the pointers. Is there no way to force it to dereference them?

Comment: @marcp Use `std::find_if` with a custom predicate that dereferences the pointers before comparing, or use [`boost::indirect_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iterator/doc/indirect_iterator.html)

Comment: Note: the expression `linename.compare( ml.linename) == 0` can be done more simply as just `linename == ml.linename`

Comment: Note having an `operator==` and `operator<` that are completely unrelated is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your container contains pointers and not objects, the comparison will be between the pointers. The only way the pointers will be equal is when they point to the exact same object. As you've noticed the comparison operator for the objects themselves will never be called.

You can use `std::find_if` and pass it a comparison object to use.

```
class MergeLineCompare
{
    MergeLine * m_p;
public:
    MergeLineCompare(MergeLine * p) : m_p(p)
    {
    }
    bool operator()(MergeLine * p)
    {
        return *p == *m_p;
    }
};

LL_iter = std::find_if(LineList.begin(), LineList.end(), MergeLineCompare(mlt));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is to use `std::find_if`  like this:

```
struct MergeLineNameCompare
{
    std::string seachname;

    MergeLineNameComp(const std::string &name) : seachname(name)
    {
    }

    bool operator()(const MergeLine * line)
    {
        return seachname.compare( line->linename ) == 0;
    }
};

LL_iter = std::find_if(LineList.begin(), LineList.end(), MergeLineNameCompare(linename) );
```

The `operator ==` (no matter wich form) is better saved for real comparison of equality.

Comment: your answer is correct, but Mark's is easier to understand. Thanks.

Comment: yea, unfortunately @mark-ransom s answer isn't totally correct.

Comment: he did not pay attention that it was intended to find the MergeLine by name, and also is using the basically not really lucky implementation of `operator ==`.

Comment: operators usually should do what they say, ... and when sooner or later the `operator ==` is changed to do a deeper comparison, the meaning of his code would change as well.

Answer (score 0):

Operator overloading can't work with pointers as it is ambiguous.

Bjarne Stroustrup :-

> References were introduced primarily to support operator overloading.
>   C passes every function argument by value, and where passing an object
>   by value would be inefficient or inappropriate the user can pass a
>   pointer. This strategy doesn’t work where operator overloading is
>   used. In that case, notational convenience is essential so that a user
>   cannot be expected to insert address− of operators if the objects are
>   large.

So, may be not best but still :-

```
   std::vector<MergeLine>LineList;
   std::vector<MergeLine>::iterator LL_iter;
```